# Simple mongo object upsert using strongloop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to do a simple upsert operation on a particular record where the field to be updated is a number type. 
I fetch the record using its record id, just +1 the number field and save it again, but for some reason it wont increment/update as seen from the log

The code is:

```
customer.findById(customerObject.id, function(err, objectResult){

    console.log(objectResult.imageIndex);

    if(!objectResult.imageIndex){
        objectResult.imageIndex = 1;
    }
    else{
        var index = objectResult.imageIndex;
        objectResult.imageIndex = index++;
        console.log(objectResult.imageIndex);
    }

    customer.upsert(objectResult, function(err, response){});
})
```

Both the console.log would display same value.. why wont it increase and update, any thing wrong with the code?

Comment: What do you get when you log `typeof(objectResult.imageIndex)'?

Comment: its prints 'number'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the statement:

```
objectResult.imageIndex = index++;
```

This is because index++ does the assignment first and then increments the value of index.

It should be either:

```
objectResult.imageIndex = ++index;
```

or

```
objectResult.imageIndex = index + 1;
```

Comment: Nice catch! I too caught it just after posting the question :)